# Query on both component parts and aggregation

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, having

I'm using sqlite3. I'd prefer to continue using it but switching is not out of the question.

I have two tables:

```
card      face
----      ----
id        id
          card_id
          name
          position
```

A `card` has one or more entries in `face`.

The canonical name of a card is the name of its faces concatenated with ' // ' in `position` order.

Example cards: 'Dark Ritual', a card with one face named 'Dark Ritual'. 'Research // Development', a card with two faces named 'Research' and 'Development'

How can I write a SELECT that finds the details of a card regardless of whether the search term is the canonical name or the name of one of the card's faces?

This is how far I got:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(name, ' // ') 
FROM 
    (SELECT c.id, f.name
    FROM card AS c
    INNER JOIN face AS f ON c.id = f.card_id
    ORDER BY f.card_id, f.position)
GROUP BY id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(name, ' // ') IN (?)
OR name IN (?)
```

This finds the card I am looking for when ? = the canonical name ('Research // Development'.) It also finds what I am looking for when I supply the name of a card with only one face ('Dark Ritual') or the *second* of two face names ('Development'). It does *not* work when I supply the first of two face names ('Research'). I know the outer query can 'see' both names because they are both present in the GROUP_CONCAT form of the name. But querying on the first face name doesn't work in the HAVING.

Can you help me understand why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN name IN (?) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Do note that parameters cannot match lists.  If you want to pass in a comma delimited list, you can try:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ',' || name || ',' LIKE '%,' || ? || ',%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks! No need for lists. The first part works great. Thanks a lot!